# run php script in the background

Tags: php, scripting, shell, putty

is there a way to launch a php script and let it run on the server until it finishes?

I use this

```
php5-cgi /var/www/script.php -q &
```

connecting via putty. When I close it (the session) the script stops! Why does it run dependent on the session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `nohup` and `disown`:

```
nohup php5-cgi /var/www/script.php -q &
disown
```

Comment: The nohup is redundant when you use disown

Answer (score 2):

If `screen` is available, use [that](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen).  Just start up a screen, run your command in it, detach the screen, and go on your merry way.

Answer (score 1):

That because your process is not decoupled from the hangup signal. Use the following instead.

```
nohup php5-cgi /var/www/script.php -q
```

You could also use a terminal multiplexer like `screen` or `tmux` if you want to be able to get back to the script output...

Answer (score 1):

Also bear in mind that PHP has a script timeout limit after which it will automatically terminate script execution. You can modify the `max_execution_time` setting in your `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` (the default is 30 seconds).